# EasyPHP gets very slow with 4 browsers running in one PC

Tags: php, performance, server, easyphp

I have been using $_SESSION variables of php for a system I created recently. The session variable gets modified from page to page. Due to this, opening multiple tabs in one browser creates problems. So I have been testing the system by running 3 or 4 browsers in one PC, which creates separate sessions in each browser. But it slows down the browser or EASYPHP a lot. What is the reason and how to improve it? Am kinda new to this.